# Address of a variable in VB

Tags: vb.net, string-concatenation

This is easy in C, how would I do it in VB?
This is what I am trying right now.

```
Dim a As String = "a"
Dim b As String = "b"
Dim c As String = "c"
Dim d As String = "d"

For Each i in {a, b, c, d}
    i = "blah" & i
End For
```

This doesn't work because this is only modifying `i` and not the underlying variable.

What I really need is a pointer!?

Comment: Make an array and `For i = 1 to 4 array(i) = "blah" & array(i) Next` or whatever the VB syntax is.

Comment: The problem here is that in VB, the runtime is free to _move your variable to a different location_ at any time behind your back. It may do this during garbage collection, for example, in order to compact your program's memory and thereby reclaim address space.

Comment: Please make your mind up - VB6 is different from VBA which is different yet from VB.NET - which one do you mean, as they are all very different from each other. Can you also explain **why** you need such a feature for these?

Comment: so how would I implement "pointer"-like logic? 
@Daniel: the thing is I am not the one creating the variable so I can not set them in the array. Creating a new array would mean i only modify my local copy of each variable

Comment: @Oded: do VB6 VBA and .net all use different rules as far as memory allocation at run time?
why? -> There are plenty of reasons to use pointers

Comment: Why do they use different rules? Because they are _different_ languages with _different_ runtimes and rules. And there is not always a good reason to revert to pointers if there are better options in the language.

Comment: @tiger13cubed vb6 and vba are pretty much (but not quite) the same. VB.Net is really a whole new animal. It's a completely new language, and uses memory rules inherited from the larger core .Net runtime, rather than it's own.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote. This is a reasonable question with some research behind it. I'm adding an upvote to balance it out.

Comment: @cyborgx37 Thanks! I'm glad someone sees the point of it! (pun intended)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VB’s `For Each` loop doesn’t support such a construct. That’s a pity but there are better ways anyway. Try to avoid loops in general:

```
Dim items = {a, b, c, d}.Select(Function (s) "blah" & s)
```

And in case that’s not valid VB (combining collection initialisers with method calls …) the following does work:

```
Dim items = (New List(Of String)() From {a, b, c, d}).Select(Function (s) "blah" & s)
```

Comment: (I hope that’s syntactically valid … not sure if VB10 allows calling a method on a list initialiser – I haven’t got VB around to test it.)

Answer (score 1):

Here, instead of the address of the variable in memory, use the address of the variable in your array:

```
Dim a As String = "a"
Dim b As String = "b"
Dim c As String = "c"
Dim d As String = "d"
Dim items = {a,b,c,d}

For i As Integer = 0 To items.Length - 1
   items(i) = "blah" & items(i)
```

Comment: this just modifies the variable in the array and not the underying variable a, b, c, and d

Comment: @tiger13cubed Well why do you have separate variables in the first place?